# why not working css in Laravel

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

developing some form in Laravel app. in the form here is input text field. I need background color to My form.
this is My form

```
<div>
<form>

     <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Task List</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Add Task" value="{{ old('name') ?: '' }}">
                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                    <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</span>
                @endif
            </div>


    </div>

</form>


</div>
```

this is My external css file

```
div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: #0000FF;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

but form color did not occured. how can fix this?

Comment: None of that CSS sets a background color of any sort.

Comment: If you are trying to set a border, `border-color` is not enough. Try `border: 1px solid #0000FF;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed the background color property in the css.
Add this
`background-color: #000 or any other color you want`